# Differential Equation-Cannot find the method to this types of problem.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJAXg.png)

I don't know the exact way to do this type of problem,can anyone kindly give me.

Comment: Why don't you substitute in the solutions from each of $a,b,c,d$ and see if the corresponding statements are true?

Comment: But,that will be very long and time-consuming.

Comment: Why did you ask the question if you can't be bothered to do what is required?

Comment: I thought ,i could do it by solving the question sorry.